# What are this designs which I found on curry leaves?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

**Curry leaves** is the plant name where I found designs, but what are the designs present on the leaf?

Location: Argentina

[image]

Comment: some leaf-mining insect larvae would be the cause. Sometimes such species are specialists (i.e., only attack one narrow range of taxa), while other times the species might be more of a generalist.